How to make sure object exist in std::unordered_map across multiple threads?
I've a std::unordered_map that maintains a data class.
I've an a timer with a periodic time duration of 1 milli-second, where by I perform some mathematical operation on data inside the data class in a for loop.
I've another single-shot timer (called timeout timer) whose timeout value is defined by a data member inside data class. On timeout a network message is transmitted and the said object is deleted.
C++ Standard : 17
Problem:
As both timers run asynchronously, sometimes object (key/value pair) inside std::unordered_map is deleted inside the timeout opertaion while for loop is being executed, this causes core dump (segmentation fault 11).
How can I check the validity of object (key/value pair) when inside for loop and avoid this error.
Code:
struct DataClass
{
    int id;
    //Some Other Data
    unsigned int timeout;
};

std::unordered_map<int, DataClass> data_map = 
{
    {1, {1, 100}},
    {2, {2, 200}},
    {3, {3, 300}}
};

void run_every_1ms(void)
{
    for (auto &[key, value] : data_map) //How do I check if particular key is detected while executing for loop
    {
        std::cout << "ID : " << key << "\t";
        std::cout << "Timeout : " << value.timeout << std::endl;
    }
}

void timeout(int id)
{
    //Send message external system
    data_map.erase(id); //Problem if erase is executed during the for loop execution in run_every_1ms
}


You have to synchronise access to the map. It's not possible to read and write the same object from different threads without synchronisation.

OT: Note that there are many non-std concurrent hash table implementations; look, e.g., at concurrent_unordered_map or concurrent_hash_map from oneTBB.

learn about std::mutex/std::scoped_lock (and possible std::shared_mutex for reader/writer access) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex. But probably you need a handrafted data structure that allows for invalidation of one key value pair while iterating over it. (or use a library as Daniel points out)

Wrap std::unordered_map<int, DataClass> with some class which will protect critical parts of code with mutex.
